# Windows Azure In Role Cache Configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I looked into following links http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185668.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185682.aspx

```
 I want to configure Windows Azure Cache (In role Caching). i found that there 
 are two options Co-located Topology and Dedicated Topology.But i m using co-located i
 had configured web.config has shown in link but i couldn't able to do that plz see below
 web.config i had configured but i m getting error
```

I m trying from last 2 days but i could get any soln..thnk you

web.config file

```
 <configSections>
<section name="dataCacheClients" 
         type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheClientsSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core" 
         allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />

<section name="cacheDiagnostics" 
         type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AzureCommon.DiagnosticsConfigurationSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AzureCommon" 
         allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
```

```
 <system.web>
 <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="AFCacheSessionStateProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="AFCacheSessionStateProvider" 
         type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider, Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache" 
         cacheName="default" dataCacheClientName="default" applicationName="AFCacheSessionState"/>
  </providers>
</sessionState>
 </system.web>

 <dataCacheClients>

 <dataCacheClient name="default">
 <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="WebRole1" />
 </dataCacheClient>
 </dataCacheClients>
 <cacheDiagnostics>
<crashDump dumpLevel="Off" dumpStorageQuotaInMB="100" /></cacheDiagnostics> 
</configuration>
```

Error.png

[image]

Comment: Please also include the bit of code where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: Looks a bit odd, though running the cache in the emulator can be a bit temperamental. This blob post may (or may not) have some useful pointers; http://gauravmantri.com/2013/08/07/making-windows-azure-caching-work-in-compute-emulator/

Comment: I dont get any exception in source code when i run this project it goes on loading for 2 to 3mins and finally shows this error page to me..

Answer (score 0):

This is purely because cache client binaries are trying to locate WebRole1 but is unable to do so because probably WebRole1 does not exist. Can you check the cache role name you have given in your configuration ?

Can you show your configuration or share a scaled down repro here ?